# Detecting if Twitter account is set up on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been following some tutorials on integrating Twitter into my application. Here is what I have so far:

```
- (IBAction)postToTweeter:(id)sender {
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                               composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"this is a test"];
        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

My storyboard has a button, and when a user taps that button, this is the code that gets called. However, this only works whenever they have a Twitter account setup on their iPhone first. How can I handle the case where a user has not set up a twitter account yet, and show them an alert instructing them to add a Twitter account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SLComposeViewController has a very handy built-in mechanism, whereby it will offer to send the user to Settings if you instantiate a ComposeViewController when the user hasn't set up / logged into the social-media service in question. To test this, all you need to do is remove the conditional so your code looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)postToTweeter:(id)sender {
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"this is a test"];
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

...and you'll find that iOS will automatically pop up an alert which will take the user through to Settings.

Note that I've found that this doesn't tend to work in the simulator, so it's best to test on a device.

Comment: Snap! Thanks for pointing that out, deleted my answer. Sorry for the misinformation!

Comment: this will not work for ios 7. when i click on Settings button .Not open my settings page